# SVM Machine Learning: Feature representation in LibSVM

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, word-count, feature-selection

Im working with Libsvm to classify written Text. (Genderclassification)

Im having Problems understanding how to create Libsvm Training data with multiple features.

Training data in Libsvm is build like this:

```
label index1:value1 index2:value2
```

Lets say i want these features:

- Top_k words: k Most used words by label
- Top_k bigrams: k Most used bigrams

So for Example the count would look like this:

```
               Word count             Bigram count
         |-----|-----------|         |-----|-----------|
         |word |   counts  |         |bigra|   counts  |
         |-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
  index  |text | +1  | -1  |  index  |text | +1  | -1  |
         |-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
      1  |this | 3   | 3   |      4  |bi   | 6   | 2   |
      2  |forum| 1   | 0   |      5  |gr   | 10  | 3   |
      3  |is   | 10  | 12  |      6  |am   | 8   | 10  |
         |...  | ..  | ..  |         |..   | ..  | ..  |
         |-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
```

Lets say k = 2, Is this how a training instance would look like?(Counts are not affiliated with before)

```
Label Top_kWords1:33 Top_kWords2:27 Top_kBigrams1:30 Top_kBigrams2:25
```

Or does it look like this (Does it matter when the features mix up)?

```
Label Top_kWords1:33 Top_kBigrams1:30 Top_kWords2:27  Top_kBigrams2:25
```

I just want to know how the feature vector looks like with multiple and different features and how to it.

EDIT:

With the updated table above, is this training data correct?:

Example

```
 1 1:3 2:1 3:10 4:6 5:10 6:8
-1 1:3 2:0 3:12 4:2 5:3  6:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libSVM representation is **purely numeric**, so

```
label index1:value1 index2:value2
```

means that each "label", "index" and "value" have to be **numbers**. In your case you have to enumerate your features, for example

```
 1 1:23 2:47 3:0 4:1
```

if some of the featues has value 0 then you can omit it

```
 1 1:23 2:47 4:1
```

remember to leave features in increasing order.

In general, libSVM **is not designed to work with texts**, and I would not recommend you to do so - rather use some already existing library which make working with text easy and wraps around libsvm (such as [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) or [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org))

Comment: Yes I know that they have to be numeric, i wanted to know how it had to be if I have these 2 features. I edited my post to clarify it

Comment: yes, updated feature representation corresponds to the table you have drawn. in general there is no meaning between features in SVM (they are independent) so you can enumerate them arbitrary. The only thing that is important is that feature K in one vector has to represent the exact same thing as feature K in the other ones; the rest is totally arbitrary. However - you should think about some proper scaling of features (like tf-idf)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `k most` words/bigrams you use for training may not be the most popular in your test set. If you want to use the most popular words in the english language you will end up with `the`, `and` and so on. Maybee `beer` and `football`are more suitable to classify males even if they are less popular. This process step is called `feature selection` and has got nothing to do with SVM. When you found selective features (beer, botox, ...) you do enumerate them and stuff them into SVM training.

For bigrams you maybe could omit feature selection as there is at most 26*26=676 bigrams making 676 features. But again I assume bigrams like `be` to be not selective as the selective match in `beer` is comleteley buried in lots of matches in `to be`. But that is speculation, you have to learn the quality of your features.

Also, if you use word/bigram counts you should normalize them, i. e. divide by the overall word/bigram count of your document. Otherwise shorter documents in your training set will have less weight than bigger ones.